# Суффикс чн

Tags: словообразование

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, слова с суффиксом -чн- и окончанием -ая, существуют в русском языке таковые?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, такого суффикса нет. Обычно мы имеем сочетание Ч+Н, например: сок - сочный, река - речной.

Есть суффикс ИЧН: гармония - гармоничный, двое - двоичный. Здесь основа перед ИЧН усекается.

Answer (score 1):

Да, тем более, что правило такого:  В прилагательных, образованных от основ на к, ц, ч, перед суффиксом ***-н-пишется ч:*** скворец - скворечный, скука - скучный, дача - дачный.  ***Правило о написании сочетаний чн в указанных условиях распространяется и на существительные: було***чн***ая***, скворечник, скворечня. Так же пишутся женские отчества от мужских отчеств на -ич: Ильинична, Никитична. Однако в некоторых словах пишется сочетание шн: городошник (от городки), двурушник (от рука), раёшник (от раёк).     Как видите, в правиле не говорится, что это суффикс.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вас интересует просто наличие слов, где после буквосочетания "чн" идет "ая" - вариантов множество. Конечная, человечная, сердечная, беспечная и т.п. и т.д. 
Если же Вас интересует именно "чн" как морфема - выше уже написано. Думаю, вопрос стоит уточнить.